# C# Interop.Excel '#N/A' Cell Value converted to -2146826246

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I have a C# application that leverages Interop.Excel (v15) to open a few workbooks of customer data, parse through them, and output some info.  The issue I'm having is that that some of the workbook cells have a value of #N/A; which in Excel speak is a CVErr indicating that some type of error exists.  In the context of our customer data, they're using #N/A to indicate Not Applicable - there is no underlying formula issue, it's simply the value they use.

When I use the below functions to traverse the worksheet rows, I get an Int value of -2146826246 every time I come across a #N/A:

```
private void traverseRows(Excel._Worksheet worksheet)
{
    //Get the used Range
    Excel.Range usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;

    //Last Row/Column
    int lastUsedRow = usedRange.Row + usedRange.Rows.Count - 1;
    int lastUsedColumn = usedRange.Column + usedRange.Rows.Columns.Count;

    foreach (Excel.Range row in usedRange.Rows)
    {
        List<String> rowData = rangeToList(row);
    }
}

List<string> rangeToList(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range inputRng)
{
    object[,] cellValues = (object[,])inputRng.Value2;
    List<string> lst = cellValues.Cast<object>().ToList().ConvertAll(x => Convert.ToString(x));
    return lst;
}
```

[image: Visual Studio Debug]

I tried examining each cell individually but that slowed the application to where it was unusable (most workbooks have 10,000 Rows X 38 Columns).  I've tried converting to Text, Value, & Value2 to no avail.  I need to be able to read in the #N/A values in their true form so I can run comparisons and later output the value to another workbook.  What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: instead of converting to string use the @ verabtim for getting it as a literal.

Comment: @SivaprasathV Where can I use @ verbatim?  The values are coming in from a COM Row Object, even in this form they have the -214682646 value

Answer (score 3):

May be below link will help you.

https://xldennis.wordpress.com/2006/11/29/dealing-with-cverr-values-in-net-part-ii-solutions/

I am not sure but just my suggestion is, As -2146826246 is the code for #N/A value, you can check cell value/text for the same and you can add #N/A as text in your list "lst".

But better approach is to use OpenXml to retrieve data from excel.

Comment: I had actually come across Mike's article during my initial research/troubleshooting phase; the article is 10+ years old and I was hoping a more elegant solution to this issue had  come to fruition over the past decade (i.e. - not having to manually translate all #N/A).  I'll look into using OpenXml.